# Make insert query idempotent - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Anybody know how I cam make this query idempotent i.e. if it got executed more than once it would not insert any duplicate records

```
    INSERT INTO MyAuthDb..AspNetUserClaims ( UserId, ClaimType, ClaimValue )
SELECT c.UserId, 'givenname', c.FirstName
FROM MyOtherDb..Contact c
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT UserId, MAX(CreatedOn) AS MaxDate
    FROM MyOtherDb..Contact
    GROUP BY UserId) c1
ON c.UserId = c1.UserId 
INNER JOIN MyAuthDb..AspNetUsers u ON c.UserId = u.Id
AND c.CreatedOn = c1.MaxDate
```

Comment: The best way to deal with this is use unique constraints on the table itself, not manage it via the query alone. You could add a "where not exists..." to the select so it won't pull any duplicates. But if you want to prevent duplicates this should also be with a constraint.

Comment: I agree but unfortunately I am not in a position to add indexes to this table. Ensuring no dupes in the insert is the only way unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `NOT EXISTS` .

```
INSERT INTO MyAuthDb..AspNetUserClaims ( UserId, ClaimType, ClaimValue )

SELECT c.UserId, 'givenname', c.FirstName
FROM MyOtherDb..Contact c
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT UserId, MAX(CreatedOn) AS MaxDate
    FROM MyOtherDb..Contact
    GROUP BY UserId) c1
ON c.UserId = c1.UserId 
INNER JOIN MyAuthDb..AspNetUsers u ON c.UserId = u.Id
AND c.CreatedOn = c1.MaxDate
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyAuthDb..AspNetUserClaims A 
WHERE A.UserId = c.UserId AND A.ClaimType = 'givenname' AND A.ClaimValue = c.FirstName )
```

Comment: This would not totally make this query idempotent but seems to respond to the user's need. Not idempotent, in a sense where if I were to change the ClaimValue, it would not update the entry but rather insert a new one.